# Share directly transferred books with Kid Account

Tags: kindle-paperwhite, drm

I have a new Paperwhite Kindle that I have used Calibre to manage directly transferring my ebooks.  I setup a Kid Account for one of my children.  When selecting book for my child to read I can only select from ebooks purchased through my Amazon account.  How do I select directly transferred books to be access from the Kid Account?